# What does it mean for a linear functional to be induced by an element?

Tags: functional-analysis

This is showing up in my homework that is asking me "show that any linear functional $\Lambda$ is not induced by any $y\in\ell_1$...." And I don't know what exactly does this mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to make the educated assumption that $\Lambda\in(\ell_\infty)^*$.  Note that $(\ell_1)^*=\ell_\infty$, so $(\ell_1)^{**}=(\ell_\infty)^*$ (here "$=$" means isometrically isomorphic), and we have the canonical isometric embedding $\ell_1\hookrightarrow(\ell_\infty)^*$.  What the exercise is (presumably) asking you to show is that $\Lambda$ is not in the image of this embedding.